# Laptop randomly presses "backspace" even with disabled keys

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard, backspace

I have the most annoying problem in this god damned world.

Every time i am browsing the internet the computer randomly presses backspace and throws me to the previous page. it happens completely randomly. Sometimes it doesn't happen for hours and other times it happens every 10 seconds or so. sometimes twice in under 3 seconds, then happens again after 20 seconds...

This happens with all browsers, text applications and windows explorer.
text applications randomly erase typed keys when writing.
Often happens immediately after opening a new page in a browser (page loads and goes back to previous mid-loading)

I have used many different software to disable the "backspace" key on my keyboard so that pressing it does nothing, yet it only reduces the rate this problem happens.

I have tried using software to swap key functions so that "backspace" does something else and vice versa, yet the same still happens (the backspace is randomly activated, not the new key after swapping).

My computer is clean, scanned with Malwarebytes and Windows Defender, cleaned with CCleaner, Hijackthis shows nothing unusual, neither does MS Autoruns, ran SFC already... Most drivers are up to date and working correctly.

Happens with or without internet connection.

Replacing the keyboard is not an option currently (its a laptop) and im delaying a reformat/windows10 as much as possible.

Any other ideas or things to try?
Any explanation about how or why this is happening?

Its driving me crazy FFS...

System specs:
ASUS N550JV
i7 4700HQ, 16gb RAM
64bit windows 8.1

Comment: did you try to use an external keyboard?

Comment: A mouse can trigger a "back" command too.

Comment: Yes, I would check your touch pad settings, including sensitivity, palm check.  Humidity changes can be a factor in touch pad performance.

Comment: I also JUST started experiencing this, and it's driving me crazy.  I replaced my keyboard, but nothing has helped.  I used this to see if there were any other keys being pressed, and noticed key code 91 was coming up at the same time.  http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html

Comment: I've been wondering whether a program like KeePass, or even my Wacom tablet could cause this sort of issue.  Do you use those?

Comment: @CaffeinatedAviator Nope, unfortunately i dont use any of those. I have given up on finding a solution for now and i hope a future clean install (after i get a new external hdd) will fix the issue. I have gotten a bit used to always select the URL bar after loading a page, so if it happens it simply erases the url instead of going back a page... Lol

Answer (score -1):

After 3 years of dealing with this problem, i finally found the root cause: ASUS ATK Package, and more specifically "hcontrol.exe"...

i still dont know how to fix this issue without completely removing the ATK Package and losing hotkey functionality such as keyboard backlight, screen on/off key, and fn+enter shortcut for calculator...